# Silverstripe framework and cms used together and separately

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

Why would one build off with just the Silverstripe Framework only and not use the CMS and vice versa. For instance routing and menus can be handled with the cms included or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the framework without using the CMS fine. The CMS without the framework however, is not possible.

There are cases, where you would have enough with just the framework, when you're building a backend application for a mobile app for example and all it has to do is provide data to that app. No need for the CMS in that case.

Comment: with the menus for instance what is the use case for completely avoiding to use the cms menu builder?

Comment: How exactly do you mean?